# Strange 'Unknown Property' error in grails

Tags: grails

i've just been giving grails a go, followed the most basic tutorial and that worked, but then moved onto the next most basic, where I create one class which has a many to one relationship to another.

say we have a class Trip which has a field airline of type Airline. the classes both have a few other fields, but they are just primitives.

now, if I create a Trip object and set the airline field to and new instance of Airline that code executes normally. but if I try execute (which i did by putting the following in grails-app/conf/Bootstrap.groovy:

```
Trip t = new Trip (...)
t.airline = new Airline(...)
println t.airline
```

it gives a huge error with a massive stack trace.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'airline'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1234)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:460)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.container.JettyServer.startServer(JettyServer.groovy:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.container.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.groovy:114)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure11.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure11.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:274)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:274)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:87)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1119)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1023)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:104)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1009)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:162)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure4_closure8_closure9.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:152)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure4_closure8_closure9.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:274)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1009)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:718)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1119)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1023)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure4_closure8.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:152)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure4_closure8.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:87)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1119)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1023)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:146)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure4_closure8_closure9.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure4_closure8_closure9.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:274)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1009)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:718)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1119)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1023)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure4_closure8.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure4_closure8.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:274)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure4.doCall(Gant.groovy:324)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:292)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure6.doCall(Gant.groovy:334)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure6.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:234)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1061)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:893)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:892)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:279)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:274)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:344)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:150)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:334)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(G
```

Comment: There are no primitives in Groovy/Grails. Everything is an object (unlike Java).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Trip class doesn't have an "airline" property.

If I have the following classes, it works fine:

```
// grails-app/domain/Trip.groovy
class Trip {
String name

static belongsTo = [airline: Airline]

String toString() { name }
}

// grails-app/domain/Airline.groovy
class Airline {
String name

static hasMany = [trips: Trip]

String toString() { name }
}
```

Then open up "grails console" and run this code:

```
Trip t = new Trip(name: "my trip")

t.airline = new Airline(name: "Delta")

assert "Delta" == t.airline.name
```

Check out the [One-to-many](http://grails.org/doc/1.1.1/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.1.2%20One-to-many) grails docs for more info.